# How to add vital few to Pareto Chart in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use this code that drow

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    data = pd.DataFrame({"Type of defect":["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Other"], "Count":[17,202,387,25,825,12,3,45]})
    data=data.set_index("Type of defect")
    data = pd.concat([data[data.index!='Other'].sort_values(by='Count',ascending = False), data[data.index=='Прочее']])
    data['Accumulated frequency'] = 100 *data['Count'].cumsum() / data['Count'].sum()
    data['Limit']=80
    data['Vital few']=np.where((data['Limit'] <= data['Accumulated frequency']) & (data['Limit'].shift(1) <= data['Accumulated frequency'].shift(1)), 0, 100)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    ax1 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Count',  kind='bar', ax=axes)
    ax2 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Accumulated frequency', marker='D', color="C1", kind='line', ax=axes, secondary_y=True)
    ax2.set_ylim([0,110])
    ax3 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Limit', color="gray", kind='line', linestyle='dashed', ax=axes, secondary_y=True)
    ax4 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Vital few', color="yellow", kind='area', ax=axes, secondary_y=True, alpha=0.1)
```

I get the [following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn04V.png)
However, I need to get [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyVb8.png)

The main problem is how to display "vital few" (Yellow area). There are also problems with the location of the legend and row/column labels. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area graphs cannot draw rectangles, so you need to use matplotlib's axvspan(). axvspan() is not reflected in the legend, so you need to add it, and use Patch to set the rectangle and label.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

ax1 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Count',  kind='bar', ax=axes)
ax2 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Accumulated frequency', marker='D', color="C1", kind='line', ax=axes, secondary_y=True)
ax2.set_ylim([0,110])
ax3 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Limit', color="gray", kind='line', linestyle='dashed', ax=axes, secondary_y=True)
#ax4 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Vital few', color="yellow", kind='area', ax=axes, secondary_y=True, alpha=0.1)
axes.axvspan(-0.5,1.25, ymax=0.95,facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.1)

handler1, label1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
#handler2, label2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
handler3, label3 = ax3.get_legend_handles_labels()
#print(label1, label2, label3)

add_legend = [Patch(facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='yellow', alpha=0.1, label='Vital few(right)')]
axes.legend(handles=handler1+handler3+add_legend)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
If it is strictly linked to the y-axis value, it can be handled by a bar chart as an alternative method. By increasing the default width, the bars will be connected.

```
ax4 = data.plot(use_index=True, y='Vital few',color='yellow', kind='bar', width=1.0,ax=axes, secondary_y=True, alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: This method is not suitable. We should base on the data['Vital few'] column rather than setting the area size manually

Comment: The y-axis of `ax.axvspan()` is limited to 0-1. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html) If this means is not appropriate, then the method is gone.

Comment: A bar chart version has also been added.